# Does the ASN1 DER null has length bytes?

Tags: asn.1, der

Does the ASN1 DER null has length bytes? I think it does not have length since it does not have value bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every ASN.1 type must have length. In case of NULL, its length has a constant value of zero, i.e. NULL is statically encoded as `05 00`.

Comment: In *DER* every value must have a tag and determinate length.  In BER there's indeterminate length forms for constructed types.